# Trying to switch header image if on home page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

New to PHP, and wondering what is wrong with this code because its definitely not switching the header img.

This is what is used to be:

```
<a href="http://www.finegra.in"><img id="logo" alt="fine grain Logo"    src="http://www.finegra.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/fineGRAINlogoGOOD-WEB.png">
```

This is what I changed it to:

```
<?php if (is_home()) { ?> <a href="http://www.finegra.in"><img id="logo" alt="fine grain Logo"  src="http://www.finegra.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/finegrain-logo-sept.png">
</a> 
<?php }
else { ?>
<a href="http://www.finegra.in"><img id="logo" alt="fine grain Logo"    src="http://www.finegra.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/fineGRAINlogoGOOD-WEB.png">
</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: What's the problem that you're getting?

Comment: I haven't debugged to check, but it should.

Comment: What would be a good way to print it out to check?

Comment: What do you get if you `echo is_home()`? You can also run that on a non-front page, where it should definitely return false

Comment: Nothing is printing out... hmm

Comment: Well if it executes the else part of your if-else construction, `is_home` is most likely returning false (check this with `var_dump(is_home());`). Are you sure you're visiting the page set as homepage? Do make sure that the `var_dump(is_home());` is somewhere in the code where it is being executed.

Comment: Yes totally sure. I am a n00b to PHP so I'm sure I'm doing something dumb

Comment: if nothing is printing, it could mean, the function is returning `false`

Comment: No actually I used var_dump(is_home()); and its returning false, so I guess that is not the home page... thanks

Comment: I looked at the wordpress codex, and a few versions ago they switched the function so that if you use a static page as your home page, is_home() refers to your posts page and you have to use is_front_page() if you

Comment: @peterbond put up a question and I'll check it as correct. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the wordpress codex, and a few versions ago they switched the function so that if you use a static page as your home page, is_home() refers to your posts page and you have to use is_front_page() if you want your static home page.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
<?php if (is_home()) : ?> <a href="http://www.finegra.in"><img id="logo" alt="fine grain Logo"  src="http://www.finegra.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/finegrain-logo-sept.png">
</a> 
<?php else : ?>
<a href="http://www.finegra.in"><img id="logo" alt="fine grain Logo"    src="http://www.finegra.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/fineGRAINlogoGOOD-WEB.png">
</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```